# want to create diamond shape using while in C

Tags: c++, c, turbo-c++

i have created the diamond using for loop but i am not able to convert it into While.

can you please help me to acheive the same goal using While loop. i tried while loop few times but it's running infinite time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main() {
    clrscr();
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=1;i<=2;i++) {
        for(j=i;j<5;j++) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(k=1;k<(i*2);k++){
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=3;i>=1;i--){
        for(j=5;j>i;j--) {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(k=1;k<(i*2);k++) {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You've made this way too complicated to start with, for such a simple task - simplify it first, then do the conversion.

Comment: Turbo c++ is stoneage! Use a more modern compiler!

Comment: `i = 1; while (i <= 2) { ... do existing things ...; i++; }`. Converting from one loop format to another does not require _much_ effort, but it does require less effort than posting a question on SO and waiting for a response.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ For small C programs less than 200 lines, which is what students do anyway, it's as good a compiler as anything else. Lack of intellisense is the biggest shortcoming of the IDE, but that's not the compiler's fault.

Comment: @sashoalm Sorry no! I have to disagree, the Tutbo C++ compiler wasn't developed any further since 1994, and has some serious flaws and also isn't even capable to parse some valid pre C++98 standards expressions correctly. There's no reason to use it, besides having to work with some very old legacy code. There's a number of good C++ toolchains and IDE's, that catch up with the latest standards, available freely on the internet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is not fashion. When a compiler is not developed anymore, it doesn't mean it rusts and stops working. Turbo-C will still compile your program just as well as it did 20 years ago. And its `printf`, `if`, `for`, and `while` are as good as the most modern compiler's. Turbo C is still used in schools in some countries, and it works for the kinds of programs that students make. Using the newest Visual Studio won't help you that much with your less-than-200-lines-of-code program.

Comment: @sashoalm _'Turbo C is still used in schools in some countries'_ Yeah, I know, and I think that this is a serious problem (that's why I evangelize)! Of course it's not that software gets _rusty_ in that sense, it stops working after lease time. But as mentioned, the compiler was already bad, buggy and flawed 20 yrs ago, and I can't see any good reason why it's still used (especially in schools).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ well i am beginner and my teacher is forcing us to use turbo c.. it's really hard and outdated. some time it gives error.

Comment: thanks for your Criticism and -7 rating for my question but i am glad that i have learned something new today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see your code for your implementation of the while loop to see what's wrong, but the general solution for converting a for loop to a while loop is this:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++)
{ 
  /*your code*/ 
}
```

becomes

```
i = 1;
while(i<=2)
{
  /*your code*/
  i++;
}
```

Make sure your iterators and decrementors are in the right places.

Comment: thanks for your help.. appreciated. logic is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You might try with placing the initialisation in front of the loop, the incrementation/decrementation at the end of the loop and leaving the condition as is. For example

```
for(k=1;k<(i*2);k++)
{
    printf("*");
}
```

translates to

```
k=1;
while(k<(i*2)){
    printf("*");
    k++;
}
```